# IntelliJ IDEA program arguments (shortcut)

Tags: intellij-idea, chef-infra

I'm installing with Chef IntelliJ for developers. The problem is that we have many different projects and common is that every project has different settings (like JDKs, Application servers etc.).

To this time, I'm just installing one instance of IntelliJ per every project and using `idea.properties` file to change config path. This is very resource wasteful as those IDEA dirs are pretty heavy.

My question is - can I just pass `idea.config.path` and `idea.system.path` variables using Windows shortcut options? I've tried to pass `-Didea.config.path` and `idea.config.path` arguments, but IntelliJ just tried to open them as new file.

I've [read here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage) that there is `IDEA_PROPERTIES` environment variable. Maybe I could change it using Windows shortcut?

Comment: You can set environment via a batch file and then start IntelliJ IDEA, see https://superuser.com/q/424001/4777 for the similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out.

All you had to do is to write in Target:
`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "set IDEA_PROPERTIES=C:/Projects/Project/config/IntelliJ/idea.properties && idea64.exe"` and in Working directory: `"C:\Program Files/IntelliJ/bin/"`.

Including full path to idea wasn't working properly even with escaping quotes as `^"`.

This way isn't ideal - all IDEA settings are different within projects. Perfect way would be if you could specify single settings (f.e. "Application Servers").